# How to run TensorBoard in Docker container without root privileges?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-datasets

I am running tensorflow-gpu in a Docker container. 
At the moment I am only able to run and access TensorBoard when I access the running Docker container using root privileges. I would like to accomplish this without using root privileges. How can this be accomplished?

**Here some information on what I am doing and what worked out:**

I am running a tensorflow-gpu using the provided docker containers from TensorFlow using the following command.

```sh
$ docker run \
-u $(id -u username):$(id -g username) \
-it --rm --runtime=nvidia \
-v $(realpath ~/data/workspace/notebooks):/tf/notebooks \
-v $(realpath ~/data/workspace/):/tf/workspace \
-v $(realpath ~/data/images/):/tf/images \
-p 8888:8888 -p 6007-6015:6007-6015 tensorflow/tensorflow:2.0.0a0-gpu-py3-jupyter
```

In the command line for starting container I added additional ports for TensorBoard.

I accomplished to run TensorBoard when doing the following.

1. The container is running (using the commands above for startup)
   → each attempt to run and access the TensorBoard out of the running Jupyter notebook fails
2. From the docker host PC I run the following commands:

   - `$ docker ps`to get the container name
   - `$ sudo docker exec -it <container name> bash` 
     → I tried this with and without `sudo`, without the command below will not work
   - `tf-docker /tf > tensorboard --logdir <log directory> --port 6007`
3. Now I am able to access the TensorBoard on `localhost:6007`

I am new to Docker, TensorFlow, and I am a newcomer to Linux (Ubuntu).
I would like to accomplish what I described above without the usage of root privileges.

- Is there a way to do it without?
- What would be the best/correct way?
- What is your best practice advice?

**Edit 2019-06-24:**
I do not know why it did not workout in the first place, perhaps I used the wrong port. This is what I accomplished until now.

- I start the container using the following command line where I changed the port for TensorBoard to 6006

  ```sh
  $ docker run \
  -u $(id -u username):$(id -g username) \
  -it --rm --runtime=nvidia \
  -v $(realpath ~/data/workspace/notebooks):/tf/notebooks \
  -v $(realpath ~/data/workspace/):/tf/workspace \
  -v $(realpath ~/data/images/):/tf/images \
  -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 tensorflow/tensorflow:2.0.0a0-gpu-py3- 
  jupyter
  ```
- Then from the command line I start a bash shell inside the docker container without using root privileges: `$ docker exec -it <container name> bash`
- After that, I start TensorBoard and use the link in the out put in a webbrowser: `tf-docker /tf > tensorboard --logdir <log directory> --port 6007`
- Instead of the previous command I could also start Tensorboard from Jupyter notebook.

  ```sh
  %reload_ext tensorboard.notebook
  %tensorboard --logdir=<log directory> --port=6006
  ```

**Edit 2019-10-09:**
Since using the TensorFlow 2.0.0 release with TensorBoard 2.0.0 I have to start TensorBoard the following:

```sh
$ tensorboard --logdir=<log directory> --host 0.0.0.0 --port 6006
```

Without explicitly adding the host option it does not work.

Comment: Have you tried running Tensorboard directly in the notebook: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/r2/tensorboard_in_notebooks.ipynb?

Comment: Yes I have. But due to the fact that I start the container without root privileges I does not work.

Comment: Yes I have. But I tried `%load_ext tensorboard.notebook` (or `%load_ext tensorboard.notebook`) with `%tensorboard --logdir="./log" --port 6007` but I got an error message.

When running a bash with root privileges in the  container, then starting the tensorboard, as described previously in my post, I am able to display TensorBoard in a Jupyter notebook.
In the Notebook I used the command from your link  `%load_ext tensorboard`. Thanks for that.

But is there a way to not use root privileges to run a bash in the Docker container?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to reproduce successfully using the command from the link [https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/r2/...](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/r2/tensorboard_in_notebooks.ipynb).

But I accomplished starting a bash in the docker container without root privileges. When now starting the TensorBoard with the command `tf-docker /tf > tensorboard --logdir <log directory> --port 6007` , I can interact with TensorBoard from a Webbrower using the address 0.0.0.0:6007.

Comment: So, if you do not use `sudo`, are you not able to run `bash` in the container, or you can run the shell but cannot run TensorBoard? And in either case, what is the error that you get? Couple things I can think of: you have to add you user to the `docker` group (see [here](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/)) (not sure since you can do `docker run` without `sudo`?); permisions on logs dir or `tensorboard` command are root-only within container.

Comment: @jdehesa
I added some further information to the original question/post. It now works. I probably made a mistake with the ports previously. Although I do not know why it then worked with root and not without root privileges.
My user does already belong to the `docker` user group.

Answer (score 0):

The steps I followed and I could visualise the results with tensorboard:

- when creating a the container, open/map an external port for tensorboard:

> ```
> > nvidia-docker run -d --name tkra_tensorb --ipc=host -it -p 8513:8090
> > -p 3014:6006 -v /data:/data tkra_tb
> ```

- inside the container, run tensorboard:

> ```
> > tensorboard --logdir /data/tkra/MyDatasets/resnet101/checkpoints/
> > --host 0.0.0.0 --port 6006
> ```

Open tensorboard in my browser: **<server_address>:3014**